# Access files uploaded with Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm researching how I might be able to pass a file, uploaded to a Cognito Forms, to our Azure API. It does not appear that JSON WebHooks will do this.

Is the Cognito Forms JSON REST API accessible?

Is this possible?

If not, do you have a recommendation for how we might do this?

I would like a file (e.g. CSV file) passed to our Azure application programmatically, NOT as a manual ("go to this page and click here") process.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The uploaded files is sent as a link with the JSON post, but this link expires quickly and has to be used right away to get or download the uploaded file.

Comment: I am getting JSON-content with the cognito-webhook, but the uploaded-file section does not contain a url. It looks like this > "YourPicture":[{"ContentType":"image/jpeg","Id":"F-lnzoL0ONYoaSERYD9efisu","IsEncrypted":false,"Name":"abc.jpg","Size":2651951}] How to fetch this image? I have the feeling i need some kind of token?